# Update selectInput error "Error in force(ui) : object 'ui' not found"

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app with work pretty well but I want to improve it and add some functionality.

My data look like:

```
NITG <- c("L447", "G24M", "G112", "F144", "B33D", "M4A1", "G432", "K54N", "K312", "K24K")
RC <- c("7E", "8E", "7D", "2G", "2B", "1D", "2J", "7M", "4H", "1D")
Pheno <- c("ZZ", "SS", "ZE", "ZZ", "ZZ", "ZLMN", "BB", "ZA", "GG", "ZZ")
GRADES <- c("D", "C", "D", "D", "C", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D")

data <- data.frame(NITG, RC, Pheno, GRADES)
```

What I want is :

When I choose a modality for my variable, for example lets take "L447" for the NITG, I want to show only "7E" for RC in RC variable filter and not all the RC I got in my data, "ZZ" for Pheno variable ...etc
I want something similar to Excel filter. Maybe I need some reactive function i'm stuck right now.

Thanks for help

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Referentiel Renault Nissan"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(selectInput("nitg",
                             "NITG:",
                             c("All", unique(filtered_df$NITG)),
                             selected = "All",
                             multiple = TRUE),
                 selectInput("pheno",
                             "Phenomenon:",
                             c("All", unique(filtered_df$Pheno)),
                             selected = "All",
                             multiple = TRUE),
                 selectInput("rc",
                             "RC:",
                             c("All", unique(filtered_df$RC)),
                             selected = "All",
                             multiple = TRUE),
                 selectInput("grade",
                             "Grades:",
                             c("All", unique(filtered_df$GRADES)),
                             selected = "All",
                             multiple = TRUE)
    ),

    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("tableprint")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$tableprint <- DT::renderDataTable({

    # Data

    NITG <- c("L447", "G24M", "G112", "F144", "B33D", "M4A1", "G432", "K54N", "K312", "K24K")
    RC <- c("7E", "8E", "7D", "2G", "2B", "1D", "2J", "7M", "4H", "1D")
    Pheno <- c("ZZ", "SS", "ZE", "ZZ", "ZZ", "ZLMN", "BB", "ZA", "GG", "ZZ")
    GRADES <- c("D", "C", "D", "D", "C", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D")

    df <- data.frame(NITG, RC, Pheno, GRADES)

    # Create filters based on inputs
    f1 <- if("All" %in% input$nitg){
      df$NITG
    } else {
      input$nitg
    }

    f2 <- if("All" %in% input$pheno){
      df$Pheno
    } else {
      input$pheno
    } 

    f3 <- if("All" %in% input$rc){
      df$RC
    } else {
      input$rc
    }

    f4 <- if("All" %in% input$grade){
      df$GRADES
    } else {
      input$grade
    }

    # Filter data
    filtered_df <- filter(df, 
                          NITG %in% f1,
                          Pheno %in% f2,
                          RC %in% f3,
                          GRADES %in% f4)

    # Update selectInput choices based on the filtered data. Update 'selected' to reflect the user input.
    updateSelectInput(session, "nitg", choices = c("All", filtered_df$NITG), selected = input$nitg)
    updateSelectInput(session, "pheno", choices = c("All", filtered_df$Pheno), selected = input$pheno)
    updateSelectInput(session, "rc", choices = c("All", filtered_df$RC), selected = input$rc)
    updateSelectInput(session, "grade", choices = c("All", filtered_df$GRADES), selected = input$grade)




    datatable(filtered_df)

  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need an implementation of `updateSelectInput()`. The demo is [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/update-input-demo.html). This is a small example, with code similar to yours.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Title"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width=3,
                 selectInput("filter1", "Filter 1", multiple = T, choices = c("All", LETTERS), selected = "All"),
                 selectInput("filter2", "Filter 2", multiple = T, choices = c("All", as.character(seq.int(1, length(letters), 1))),
                                selected = "All")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("tableprint")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$tableprint <- DT::renderDataTable({

    # Data
    df <- tibble(Letters = LETTERS, Numbers = as.character(seq.int(1, length(letters), 1)))

    # Create filters based on inputs
    f1 <- if("All" %in% input$filter1) LETTERS else input$filter1
    f2 <- if("All" %in% input$filter2) as.character(seq.int(1, length(letters), 1)) else input$filter2

    # Filter data
    filtered_df <- filter(df, 
                          Letters %in% f1,
                          Numbers %in% f2)

    # Update selectInput choices based on the filtered data. Update 'selected' to reflect the user input.
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter1", choices = c("All", filtered_df$Letters), selected = input$filter1)
    updateSelectInput(session, "filter2", choices = c("All", filtered_df$Numbers), selected = input$filter2)

    datatable(filtered_df)

  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: thank you very much i just follow the example but i get one error about the apply lauch can you check my script thanks again